# How do I use JFreeChart auto ranges properly?

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

I was manually creating a range for the y-axis on the graph I was creating, but saw that there were a few properties indicating that JFreeChart can generate them for you.

It already generates a sensible maximum value for the y-axis, but no matter what I try and do, I cannot get the `setAutoRangeIncludesZero(boolean)` to actually be taken into account when generating the graph.

Here is the relevant code that generates and manipulates the graph:

```
barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Classifiers' accuracy for " + position + "s", 
           "Missing Value Imputation Method Combination", 
           "Average accuracy (%)", dataset, 
           PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, false, false);

plot = (CategoryPlot)barChart.getCategoryPlot();
xAxis = (CategoryAxis)plot.getDomainAxis();
xAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.UP_45);

yAxis = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();
yAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

barChartImage = new File(position + "-Classification" + ".png");
```

I have also tried first getting the y-axis as a `ValueAxis`, using `setAutoRange(true)` and then casting the y-axis to a `NumberAxis` and using `setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false)`.

Every time, the y-axis still starts at 0.

Comment: What values do you have and what is the range of the axis?

Comment: My values range between about 48 and 74 and at the moment the y-axis is 0-78

Comment: Check the following values (just e.g. print them): `plot.getDataRange (yAxis)`, `yAxis.getRangeType ()`, `yAxis.getAutoRangeIncludesZero ()`, `yAxis.getFixedAutoRange ()`, `yAxis.getAutoRangeMinimumSize ()`, `yAxis.getAutoRangeStickyZero ()`.

Comment: `plot.getRange(yAxis)` = 0.0 and 70.45 (don't know why it starts at 0, none of the data in the dataset is 0)
`yAxis.getRangeType()` = `RangeType.FULL`
`yAxis.getAutoRangeIncludesZero()` = false
`yAxis.getFixedAutoRange()` = 0.0
`yAxis.getAutoRangeMinimumSize()` = 1.0E-8
`yAxis.getAutoRangeStickyZero()` = true

Comment: Well, if plot range returns zero as lower bound, no wonder the axis includes zero in its autorange. Are you absolutely sure there are actually no zero values in the dataset (maybe somehow "hidden")?

Comment: I inspected the dataset object and looked at both rows, and neither had any zero values in them, so I don't understand where it's picking up a zero from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71587/discussion-between-doublep-and-matt-williams).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @doublep for the answer in a private chat.

I was using a BarChart and it turns out the `BarRenderer` by default, sets the base of the range to be 0.
To override this you just need to get the renderer from the plot object and cast it to type `BarRenderer` and then call `setIncludeBaseInRange(false)` and that will prevent the default value of 0 being included in the range.